# Not matching nested occurrences with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working on an HTML editor in JavaScript, trying to implement an undo-feature.

So I have this HTML code (with hidden comments for storing app states):

```
<!-- RECONSTRUCT: 'test1' -->
<h1>FOO</h1>
<!-- END RECONSTRUCT -->
<h1>BAR</h1>
<!-- RECONSTRUCT: 'test2' -->
<h1>FOOFOO</h1>
<!-- END RECONSTRUCT -->
```

which I need to transform into this HTML code:

```
test1
<h1>BAR</h1>
test2
```

So basically, the html comments "save" an old state which I need to restore the code to.

So what I want a Regex to achieve is:

```
[0:"test1", 1:"<h1>FOO</h1>", 2:"test2", 3:"<h1>FOOFOO</h1>"]
```

or something similar.

The problem is, when I try to use Regex like this:

```
src.match(/<!-- RECONSTRUCT: '(.*)' -->(.*)<!-- RECONSTRUCT END -->/g)
```

I get

```
[0: "<!-- RECONSTRUCT: 'test1' --> ... FOO ... BAR <!-- RECONSTRUCT ... FOOFOO ... ->"]
```

so the complete input as an result, since its a valid match.
I also don't get it working with negative look ahead:

```
<!-- RECONSTRUCT: '(.*)' -->((?!RECONSTRUCT:).)*
```

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript `.` does not match newline characters and there is no modifier (like `s`) available for overriding this behaviour. The way to do it in JavaScript is to use `[^]` instead of `.`, when newlines are allowed to match also.

Also make some patterns lazy with `?`:

```js
var src = `<!-- RECONSTRUCT: 'test1' -->
<h1>FOO</h1>
<!-- END RECONSTRUCT -->
<h1>BAR</h1>
<!-- RECONSTRUCT: 'test2' -->
<h1>FOOFOO</h1>
<!-- END RECONSTRUCT -->`;

src = src.replace(
    /<!--\s*RECONSTRUCT:\s*'(.*?)'\s*-->[^]*?<!--\s*END RECONSTRUCT\s*-->/g, '$1');

console.log(src);
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the quick and amazingly light answer!
Really appreciate it, and wish I could tip you a drink for it.

Comment: Quick question: how does your regex solves the "nested occurences"-problem? Why is the input not interpreted as a single (and only) result like in my trys?

Comment: When I tried your `match`, I got `null` as result (which is normal because `.*` does not go across newlines), so I cannot really compare. Also, I don't see any truly nested occurrences in your sample. What do you mean with *nested*?

Comment: like that: all input is a valid match since it starts with <!-- RECONSTRUCT ... and ends with "<!-- END RECONSTRUCT -->". (with an other reconstruct in between). That was my main problem with this task when using match(). maybe its just replace(), which "solves" it?

Comment: But in the sample they are not truly nested as the first `END RECONSTRUCT` belongs to the first `RECONSTRUCT`, and the second to the second. One stops before the other begins. As I said, I could not reproduce what you get with `match`.